# Run time error 3021 - EOF or BOF is true or the current record has been deleted

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM Equipas WHERE ([ID - Funcionário] LIKE '" & idfunc & "' AND [ID - Tarefa] LIKE ' " & idtask & "' );", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
rst.Delete adAffectCurrent
rst.Update
rst.Close
```

I receive the runtime error 3021 however the query is not empty.

Comment: Try dropping the `;` at the end of the SQL.  If that still doesn't work, try printing out the generated SQL and running it directly in Access.

Comment: The issue in the duplicate question was the `LIKE` wild card character.  Although this question also uses `LIKE`, there is no indication that a wild card is involved.

Answer (score 7):

> *"I receive the runtime error 3021 however the query is not empty."*

Double check that point.

```vb
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Equipas " & _
    "WHERE ([ID - Funcionário] LIKE '" & _
    idfunc & "' AND [ID - Tarefa] LIKE ' " & idtask & "' );"
Debug.Print strSelect
rst.Open strSelect, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox "recordset is empty"
Else
    rs.MoveLast
    MsgBox "recordset contains " & rs.RecordCount & " rows"
End If
'rst.Delete adAffectCurrent
'rst.Update
rst.Close
```

If that version of the code tells you *"recordset is empty"*, go to the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) to examine the `SELECT` statement the code built.  You can copy the statement text and paste it into SQL View of a new Access query for testing.

My best guess is the query returns no rows because it includes a space just before the value of `idtask`, and no `[ID - Tarefa]` values match space plus `idtask`:

```vb
idfunc & "' AND [ID - Tarefa] LIKE ' " & idtask & "' );"
                                    ^ here
```