# VBA Run-time error 3021, SQL statement works in access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I'm getting the run-time error 3021:

> Either BOF of EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted

when I debug this sub suggesting my record set is empty.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cs As String
Dim sql As String

cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
cn.Open cs
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT dbo_vwScaEuLevel.PropertyNameParcelTiebacks, dbo_vwScaEuLevel.PsdPrimaryAddress, " & _
        "dbo_vwScaEuLevel.VsTotalEconomicUnit, dbo_vwScaEuLevel.AssessYear, dbo_vwScaEuLevel.PrimaryPin, " & _
        "dbo_vwScaEuLevel.BsdAvgYearBuilt, dbo_vwScaEuLevel.PsdNeighborhood, dbo_vwScaEuLevel.ModelName, " & _
        "FROM ((dbo_vwScaEuLevel INNER JOIN dbo_ScaEuLevelOccupancy ON (dbo_vwScaEuLevel.PrimaryPin = dbo_ScaEuLevelOccupancy.PrimaryPin) " & _
        "AND (dbo_vwScaEuLevel.AssessYear = dbo_ScaEuLevelOccupancy.AssessYear)) INNER JOIN dbo_cama_ComBldgSec " & _
        "ON dbo_vwScaEuLevel.PropertyID = dbo_cama_ComBldgSec.PropertyID) INNER JOIN dbo_vwPropertyOwner ON " & _
        "dbo_vwScaEuLevel.PropertyID = dbo_vwPropertyOwner.PropertyID " & _
        "WHERE (((dbo_vwScaEuLevel.AssessYear)= " & Range("C1").Value & ") AND ((dbo_vwScaEuLevel.BsdAvgYearBuilt) Is Not Null) " & _
        "AND ((dbo_vwScaEuLevel.PsdNeighborhood) Between '800' And '900') AND ((dbo_vwScaEuLevel.TotalResidentialSquareFootage)=0) " & _
        "AND ((dbo_vwScaEuLevel.ModelName) Like '*' & '" & Range("C2").Value & "' & '*'))"
```

As suggested from another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532259/run-time-error-3021-eof-or-bof-is-true-or-the-current-record-has-been-deleted), I included the following and get the "recordset is empty" message.

```
rs.Open sql, cn
Debug.Print sql
If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox "recordset is empty"
Else
    rs.MoveLast
    MsgBox "Recordset contains " & rs.RecordCount & " rows"
End If

rs.close
cn.close
```

I copied the SQL from the immediate window to access and it gives me exactly what I need. Any ideas why my recordset may be coming up empty?

Comment: I strongly recommend you execute the query directly on SQL server, instead of executing it in Access on linked tables that reside in SQL server (I assume because of the `dbo_` names). You're introducing a lot of overhead and extra chance for errors by executing queries through Access.

Comment: SQL construct in VBA should work without semicolon although doesn't hurt to use. Remove the comma from end of 3rd line after `ModelName`. That comma should cause failure in Access query object as well.

Comment: @June7 I should clarify the above code only includes a few of the over 30 fields I'm actually querying... I just forgot to remove that comma. My actual code does not include a comma after the last select field before my FROM statement.

Comment: 30+ fields! Maybe use * to mass pull fields. `dbo_vwScaEuLevel.*` Don't see reason for empty recordset. Cannot replicate issue. Suggest you test by building the SQL in stages. Expand it until it fails.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I switched my wildcard to % instead of * on my LIKE operator and that did the trick.